# System.IndexOutOfRangeException exceptio while fetching JSON data with ADO .NET

Tags: c#, json, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a simple table with user details:
[[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQuY7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQuY7.png)

This is the SP that I have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login]
    @userName VARCHAR(50)
    ,@password VARCHAR(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT USERID AS Id, (FIRST_NAME+' '+LAST_NAME) AS NAME, EMAIL AS email FROM [dbo].    [USER] WHERE USERNAME = @userName AND PASSWORD = @password
    FOR JSON AUTO
    END
```

The ADO .NET code that I wrote is as follows:

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["Id"].ToString() + ' ' + reader["email"].ToString());
}
```

When I am trying to debug the code or just run it, it throws the following exception in the line with 'Console.WriteLine' statement:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException
> HResult=0x80131508
> Message=Id
> Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

When I modify my SP to not have 'FOR JSON AUTO' part, the code runs fine and I get the expected result.
But as soon as I add 'For JSON AUTO', I start getting the exception.

I searched some sites for the resolution, but I did not find any. Most of them suggested to check the column name if it is right, so I copied and pasted the column names directly from the SP. But to no avail.

Anyone having any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: You have bigger issues: you appear to be storing a plain text password. Don't!!

Comment: If you're gonna use a data reader, you don't need or want `For Json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your data is transformed into a JSON array and the dataset returns the result as a single row and column.

To get the first column from the row:

```cs
reader.GetValue(0)
```

And you should use the JSON serializer library such as *System.Text.Json* or *Newtonsoft.Json* to extract the value as `JArray`.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
    JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    
    foreach (JObject jObj in jArray)
        Console.WriteLine(jObj["Id"].ToString() + ' ' + jObj["email"].ToString());
}
```

Since the dataset will return only a single value, you may replace the `.ExecuteReader()` with [`.ExecuteScalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.1).

```cs
object value = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();  
JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(value.ToString());
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/65lF1S)

Comment: [Demo `.ExecuteScalar()` @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h2jj9G)

Comment: Thanks Yong Shun! this worked!